# Prepend set of characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to prepend a backlash to all occurrences of characters from a set, say `'"\`, in a given string.

For example, given the string

```
He said "I don't know."
```

it should be replaced with

```
He said \"I don\'t know.\"
```

How do I do this in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
["'\\]
```

In order to use this in a Java string literal, the double quote and both backslashes need to be escaped.

The replacement string should be this:

```
\\$0
```

Here `$0` is a reference to the match. The backslash needs to be escaped otherwise the $ becomes literal. Again the backslashes need to be escaped in a Java string literal. The resulting code looks like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[\"'\\\\]", "\\\\$0");
```

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/7rRyn)

Comment: Thanks for explanation and working code! I've never seen ideone and it looks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

there might be an easier way, but here's one

```
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"|\')");

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     int start = 0;
     Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
     while (m.find()) {
           int end = m.start();
           sb.append(s.substring(start, end));
           sb.append("\\").append(m.group(1));
           start = m.end();
     }
     sb.append(s.substring(start));

     String result = sb.toString();
```

where s is your input string

Answer (score -1):

try using the following regexes

1. to find the quotes `/['"]/g`
2. to replace the quotes `\$&`

hope this works.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match backslashes, and the backslash in your replacement string needs to be escaped with another backslash--and that's assuming you're working in *JavaScript*.  For a **Java** solution, see @Mark's answer.

Comment: i just gave it generic format from gskinner app.. it was not meant for a specific language. thanks for your comments.

Comment: [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) is powered by ActionScript, which follows the ECMAScript regex standard (but is actually much more powerful).  There are many online testers out there; your answers will be much more helpful if you use one that matches the flavor specified in the question.  [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) is a good one for Java.